# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Error on ASP.NET using Entity and WebAPI 2

Tags: mysql, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api

I know there have been a few of these posts but i've looked through all that ive found and tried their solutions without success and im getting a bit desperate now. This needs to be finished by the end of tomorrow.
Im building a website that uses a MySQL db and Web API 2 on Entity Framework at the backend, then js/jax on the front end, all hosted on Azure.
I was making some more HTML pages, nothing to do with any of the config files, then I random started getting  this error.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://uocfabianwiles.azurewebsites.net/api/Courses. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:56401' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Im using the below code to enable CORS

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

None of the https requests through Swagger return me with anything but an error, yet they were working fine this morning.

What i've tried:
Adding this to the controllers, as per http://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://msauocfabianwiles.azurewebsites.net/api/students", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

Adding custom headers to to the web.config file
Changing databases
Reinstalling Entity and MySQL Nuget packages
Running locally with debugging in Visual Studio - no errors from VS

Edit: I tried deleting the DB/website and made new ones, that somehow resolved the CORS error but instead is now giving me a 500 Internal Server Error, but only maybe 70% of the time, the other 30% it loads fine without issues

Answer (score 1):

I used to have this error but I solved it by using the code below.

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyProject.Api.Startup))]
namespace MyProject.Api {
    public class Startup {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);            
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it works. If not, Try `config.EnableCors();` (without attribute) in WebApiConfig.

Example:

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            config.EnableCors();

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ill definitely give your code a go, although im not sure if the code is meant to be in it's own file with any specific name?

Comment: u mean, Startup? This is how we used to name the startup file for Owin. I think you can give any file name you want as long as the type you specified in OwnStartup attribute are the same.

Comment: Thanks, ill give it ago. Sorry that I appear inexperienced, only started learning these technologies this time last week (not me being lazy, it's just been poorly organised for the less experienced )I have to get this done tomorrow.

Comment: Its all right.. :) I am also not sure my answer will help to solve your issue but hopefully, it will. I am just sharing my experience that I got when I have the same issue.

Comment: Ok well it didn't fix it, instead I deleted the DB/website and made new ones, that somehow resolves the CORS error but instead is now giving me a 500 Internal Server Error, but only maybe 60% of the time, the other 40% it loads fine without issues

Comment: 500 error means there might be some errors in your code. Did you try using Startup.cs or WebApiConfig.cs or both? If you still want to try, just use only Startup.cs with `app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);  ` only (remove `config.EnableCors()`) from WebApiConfig.cs and then try to redeploy it? After that, you can manually stop the azure webapp and start again a few seconds later. I am calling webapi from js in my project as well. It works for me after I use `app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);  `